# Tree style options list in Angular

Tags: angularjs, tree, html-select

I want a drop down `select` and `option` list which displays a tree, in that sub items are indented so its obvious to the user they are child items.  When I run this, literally nothing shows in the `select`.  Ideally Id like it to display [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/faatLLLk/)

My second problem is that using padding within the options wont work I have to use `&nbsp;`, but how can I pass nesting information down the template to output the required number of spaces?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_option_renderer.html">
    <option>{{data.Name}}</option>

    <!-- Would want 1 &nbsp; per level to indent properly, how? -->
    &nbsp;<option ng-repeat="data in data.Children" ng-include="'tree_option_renderer.html'">
</script>

<select id="folderList" ng-show="operatesOnSelector == 0">
    <option ng-repeat="group in addressbook" ng-include="tree_option_renderer.html"></option>
</select>
```

My data looks a little like this:

```
{
    Id: 0,
    Name: "Level 1",
    Children: [
        {
            Id: 1,
            Name: "level 2",
            Children: []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `<select>` doesn't support nested optgroups

Comment: No but you can use &nbsp; to indent

Comment: Right... so, why do you have `<div>` there?

Comment: If you read my comment, I dont know how to do the `&nbsp;` stuff in Angular, the div was my initial attempt, the jsFiddle I provided shows it with `&nbsp;` - Ill update my question to be clearer

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the edit

Comment: Np, wasnt overly clear initially anyway, I udpated

Answer (score 1):

Use [NgHierarchicalSelector](https://github.com/lukemurray/NgHierarchicalSelector/) will resolve your problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, but the quick answer is to use a custom directive that does some rudimentary pre-order tree traversal to flatten the structure while keeping the nesting level, and then render `<options>` elements.

The reason I find this question interesting is because you can take the solution "almost" all way without a custom directive, so long as you *don't use* an `<option>`.

**Challenge 1:** `ng-repeat` over a nested structure:

```
<div ng-repeat="l in data" ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemTemplate">
  {{l.Name}}
  <div ng-repeat="lNext in l.Children"
       ng-init="l = lNext"
       ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></div>
</script>
```

this could actually work with CSS:

```
<style>
  div > div {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

**Challenge 2:** track nesting levels - can be accomplished with `ng-init`s:

```
<div ng-repeat="l in data" ng-include="'itemTemplate'" ng-init="level = 1"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemTemplate">
  {{l.Name}}
  <div ng-repeat="lNext in l.Children"
       ng-init="level = level + 1; l = lNext"
       ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></div>
</script>
```

**Challenge 3:** generate N `&nbsp;` based on the nesting level:

This requires a function to be defined on the `$scope` (that's already kinda funky)

```
$scope.repeat = function(str, n){
  return Array(n).join(str);
};
```

and add a `<span>` before `{{l.Name}}`:

```
<span ng-init="arr = repeat('&nbsp;', level)" ng-bind-html="arr"></span>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TIMjxDVQLCi3WkhanJ3w)

**...** And this is where the requirement to have this done with `<option>`s unravels this entire solution, and that is because `<option>`s cannot be nested, while the solution above requires nesting (otherwise, the nested structure cannot be traversed).

So, this answer is a really a non-answer, because the actual answer is kinda boring.